# JMESPathTypeError when using json_query filter in Ansible with starts_with

Tags: ansible, boto3, jmespath

I am trying to filter results that arrived from boto3 in Ansible.

When I use json query on the results without the "[?starts_with(...)]" it works well, but when adding the starts_with syntax:

```
"state_machines[?starts_with(name,'hello')].state_machine_arn"
```

In order to filter results:

```
{u'boto3': u'1.4.4', u'state_machines': 
[{u'state_machine_arn': u'<state machine arn 1>', u'name': u'hello_world_sfn', u'creation_date': u'2017-05-16 14:26:39.088000+00:00'}, 
{u'state_machine_arn': u'<state machine arn 2>', u'name': u'my_private_sfn', u'creation_date': u'2017-06-08 07:25:49.931000+00:00'}, 
{u'state_machine_arn': u'<state machine arn 3>', u'name': u'alex_sfn', u'creation_date': u'2017-06-14 08:35:07.123000+00:00'}], 
u'changed': True}" }
```

I expect to get the first state_machine_arn value: "state machine arn 1"

But instead, I get the exception:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: JMESPathTypeError: In function contains(), invalid type for value: <lamdba_name>, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: "unknown" fatal: [localhost]: FAILED!
=> {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: How do you get this boto results and how you feed it into `json_query` filter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that json_query filter expects to get a dictionary with ascii strings, but what you're providing it are unicode strings (notice the `u'blabla'` in your input).

This is an issue with json_query that apparently got introduced in Ansible 2.2.1 (although that is not really clear), here are some more details:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20379#issuecomment-284034650

I hope this gets fixed in a future version, but for now this is a workaround that worked for us:

```
"{{ results | to_json | from_json | json_query(jmespath_query) }}"
```

Where `jmespath_query` is a variable that contains a `starts_with` query.
This trick of going to and from json turns the unicode strings into ASCII ones :)

Comment: `json_query filter expects to get a string`. Are you sure? I bet it expects object(dictionary). `from_json` does exactly that: converts JSON-string to object.

Comment: You are right, I meant that the dictionary should contain ascii and not unicode strings. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to writing `| to_json | from_json | json_query(…)` everywhere, you can monkey-patch Ansible's `json_query` filter by creating the following `filter_plugins/json_bug_workaround.py` file:

```
import json
from ansible.parsing.ajson import AnsibleJSONEncoder
from ansible.plugins.filter.json_query import json_query 

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            # Workaround for Unicode bug https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547305
            'json_query': lambda data, query: json_query(
                json.loads(json.dumps(data, cls=AnsibleJSONEncoder)),
                query
            ),
        }
```

Then you can just use `| json_query(…)` naturally.  This shim does the equivalent of calling [`| to_json | from_json`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.1/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py) for you.

You can put it inside your role (`roles/role_name/filter_plugins/json_bug_workaround.py`) or anywhere in [Ansible's plugin search path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#local-plugins).